# How do I remove a single breakpoint with GDB?

Tags: gdb

I can add a breakpoint in GDB with:

```
b <filename>:<line no>
```

How can I remove an existing breakpoint at a particular location?

Comment: have you tried D <filename>:<lino no> ?

Comment: Unfortunately no: It produces an error: "warning: bad breakpoing number at or near '<file>:<no>'"

Comment: @Eineki it's the breakpoint no., not the line no. like : `d <filename>:<breakpoint no>`.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try these ([reference](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_31.html)):

```
clear linenum
clear filename:linenum
```

Answer (score 373):

You can list breakpoints with:

```
info break
```

This will list all breakpoints. Then a breakpoint can be deleted by its corresponding number:

```
del 3
```

For example:

```
 (gdb) info b
 Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
  3      breakpoint     keep y   0x004018c3 in timeCorrect at my3.c:215
  4      breakpoint     keep y   0x004295b0 in avi_write_packet atlibavformat/avienc.c:513
 (gdb) del 3
 (gdb) info b
 Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
  4      breakpoint     keep y   0x004295b0 in avi_write_packet atlibavformat/avienc.c:513
```

Comment: You can also abbreviate `info break` to `i b`

Comment: you can also delete multiple breakpoints like "(gdb) del 3 4 5"

Comment: Or you can even use ranges as in `del 1-4`

Answer (score 26):

You can delete all breakpoints using

```
del <start_breakpoint_num> - <end_breakpoint_num>
```

To view the *start_breakpoint_num* and *end_breakpoint_num* use:

```
info break
```

Comment: But that wasn't the question: *"...remove* ***an existing breakpoint at a particular location***"

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
clear fileName:lineNum   // Removes all breakpoints at the specified line.
delete breakpoint number // Delete one breakpoint whose number is 'number'
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete the breakpoint at the current line you can also run `clear` without any arguments:

```
clear
```

Handy for when you hit something you didn't want to hit.

TODO any way to disable instead of deleting without typing the line number? `disable` without arguments just disables all breakpoints. I wish I could `disable .` or something like that.